# Bind current date time to TextBox and update the source property when I update it (WPF)

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to bind current date and time to a text box and I want to update the source property when I change the value.I'm using MVVM code structure and I want this task to be done in .xaml file

Comment: Can you add some details ? what do you mean by changing the value ?

Comment: In my Entity Class I have a property called 'SampleCurrentDate'. I have binded that property to a TextBox in .xaml file. When I change the date in UI, I want to change the SampleCurrentDate property value also,

Answer (score 0):

User observale property from WPF to achieve same thing.

```
public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

  private string _mytime;
  public string MyTime
  {
      get { return _mytime; }
      set { _mytime= value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MyTime"); }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
  {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (null != handler)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
  }
}
```

Now what you need to do is attach MyTime property in your XAML file and whenever you update MyTime in your class file your will see the updated value on UI.

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding MyTime}/>
```

Comment: Thank you Dnyanesh, I'm not clear your answer. Can you be more specific please.

Comment: Thank you @Dnyanesh, but How do I set the current DateTime in .xaml file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the property Binding, add `Mode=TwoWay` to ensure the update from the UI to the ViewModel is enabled.

You may need to add a `Converter=...` property with an implementation of IValueConverter that converts from `DateTime` to `string` and vice versa.

If you want the binding to update after each keypress and not only on lost focus, you have to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger`-Property of the ´Binding´.

Comment: Thank you eFloh, I refer this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383537/wpf-how-to-bind-current-date) and like @BrokenGlass answer I created UserControl.Resource like this

<UserControl.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="date" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:DateTime}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

and My TextBox is like this

<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource date},Path=Now, Mode=TwoWay}" />

my problem is , I have a property called 'SampleCurrentDate' in my Entity Class and How do I set that property to textBox with binding to effect the change I'm doing?

Comment: you can't bind the input value from one side (StaticResource) and update another one (EntityClass). You have to set the DateTime.Now in your Entity Class as default value (in ctor for example) and bind to that property directly.